# Trying to python takes a variable in to Create Table

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to python takes a variable when it ask for the data base name but it does not work this is my code, I do not know whan I'm doing wrong.

any idea ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb

name_db = raw_input('Type Data Base Name : ')

bd = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","9090i","clientes" )

cursor = bd.cursor()

sql = "CREATE TABLE name_db (NOMBRE  CHAR(20) NOT NULL, APELLIDO CHAR(20), EDAD INT, SEXO CHAR(1), SALARIO FLOAT )"

cursor.execute(sql)

bd.close()
```

Comment: I don't know `phython` but my guess is you're trying to create a table named `name_db`.  Since that's an entered field (I presume), it should be combined to the sql instead of hard coded within a string.  Parameterized queries are preferable, but I don't know if that's supported in python...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE name_db (NOMBRE  CHAR(20) NOT NULL, APELLIDO CHAR(20), EDAD INT, SEXO CHAR(1), SALARIO FLOAT )"
```

to

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE {name} (NOMBRE  CHAR(20) NOT NULL, APELLIDO CHAR(20), EDAD INT, SEXO CHAR(1), SALARIO FLOAT )".format(name = name_db)
```

The {name} is Python's syntax for string replacement so this should create a constant SQL String that has the value you typed in substituted for the table name.

To check this it's a good idea to print out the SQL before you execute it.  That makes it easier for you to see why the code isn't working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the print function works well but mysql give an error like this: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{nombredb} (NOMBRE  CHAR(20) NOT NULL, APELLIDO CHAR(20), EDAD INT, SEXO CHAR(1)' at line 1")
.

Comment: That means that the braces {} are being included in the final string after the Python .format() replacement and they shouldn't be.  Did you enter "nombredb" or "{nombredb}" in response to the raw_input?  The first (without the braces) is correct.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer so that people know this question is answered.